# Customizing the UI in SharePoint Online - SP Designer solution or not?

Tags: customization

I am completely new to SharePoint and I have very little programming experience. I have been tasked to build a SharePoint site and try to customize the look beyond the simple ribbon options at the top. I already built the site within the in-browser SharePoint that comes with Office 365. Now I want to edit that site further.

Could someone help me with the following questions?

1. Do I have the option of downloading the SharePoint site I made and import it into SharePoint Designer? If there a way to do this?
2. Is there a way to edit the HTML of the website as a whole?
3. If there is a better option to customize the site that you think would suit someone with limited programming experience, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: Before you go too in-depth with this site, I believe you need to review some resources and training.  Here is a very basic starting point - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/sharepoint-site-branding-and-page-customization-solutions

Answer (score 0):

1. SharePoint Designer basically opens the site and you can access all its contents (Pages/Libraries etc.). Any changes you made will affect the site. That means you will be updating the live site.
2. Each site has an associated master page. So you can edit the master page to give a nice look and feel to the entire site.
3. Its better to buy a SharePoint beginner book and then try it out before you go further down.